# Sed - replace value in file with regex match in another file

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to code a bash script in a build process where we only have a few tools (like grep, sed, awk) and I am trying to replace a value in an ini file with a value from a regular expression match in another.

So, I am matching something like "^export ADDRESS=VALUE" in file export_vars.h and putting VALUE into an ini file called config.ini in a line with "ADDRESS=[REPLACE]".  So, I am trying to replace [REPLACE] with VALUE with one command in bash.

I have come across that sed can take an entire file and insert it into another with a command like

```
sed -i -e "/[REPLACE]/r export_vars.h" config.ini
```

I need to somehow refine this command to only read the pattern match from export_vars.h.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you wish for the line in `export_vars.h` (e.g. `export ADDRESS=VALUE`) to replace a line already in `config.ini` (e.g. ADDRESS=VALUE)?  I assume the thing you are trying to match here is ADDRESS and you wish to replace VALUE in this example?

Comment: Yes - or just replace the [REPLACE] in the ini file with VALUE.  I guess either would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. You need to be looking at awk for what you're trying to do. Something like:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="=" }
NR==FNR { 
    if ( $1 == "export ADDRESS" ) {
        value = $2
    }
    next
}
{ sub(/\[REPLACE\]/,value); print }
' export_vars.h config.ini
```

Untested, of course, since you didn't provide testable sample input/output.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.  Need to learn awk more, apparently, because we have other tasks like this.

Comment: more tasks - more SO questions

Comment: You're welcome. To learn awk, read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. All other books are obsolete, and all online tutorials are buggy and/or misleading. If you are considering doing anything in sed that uses constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) then you are using the wrong tool. Sed is for `s/old/new/`, that is all, and even then has caveats (e.g. it doesn't understand strings). All of the other arcane sed constructs became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented and are useful today only for mental exercise, never for production software.

Comment: @EdMorton, what are your thoughts and your opinion about this book "Sed and Awk 101 Hacks" ?

Comment: I've never heard of it but from the title 2 things spring to mind: 1) You do NOT need any book to tell you how to use sed properly (`s/old/new/` - done!), 2) it has the word `Hacks` in it - who in their right mind would want to learn how to write hacks instead of idiomatically correct, elegant code? Oh I see, it was written by the guy with the terrible awk "tutorial" at thegeekstuff - no, avoid that like the plague.

Comment: @EdMorton, right, and I didn't find it at any online book-shop ... He wrote *I have been adding 1’s and 0 ‘s for more than 17 years in the IT industry* ...

Comment: I wonder what answer he gets when he adds `1` plus `0` :-). Take a look at his tutorial [3. Awk RS Example: Record Separator variable](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/). He says `Awk RS defines a line` - no it doesn't, it separates records. He shows `RS="\n\n"` to read blank-line separated records - no you don't you use `RS=""` and `RS="\n\n"` would be gawk-specific anyway due to multi-char RS. I've provided corrections to the examples on his site in the past but he doesn't listen.

Comment: yeah, some guys are designing anti-patterns )

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk '/ADDRESS/{if(a!="")$0=a;else a=$NF}NR>FNR' export_vars.h config.ini
ADDRESS=VALUE
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
/ADDRESS/ {                 # when ADDRESS is found in record
    if(a!="") $0=a          # if a is set (from first file), use it
    else a=$NF }            # otherwise set a with the last field
NR>FNR                      # print all record of the last file
' export_vars.h config.ini  # mind the order
```

This solution does not tolerate space around `=` since `$0` is replaced with `$NF` from the other file.